# What is this kitchen cupboard arm?

Tags: kitchens

Need to replace this arm as it is supposed to attach to a gas strut but the inside thread has been worn out, i just cant seem to find the name of it.

[image]

Comment: What's the stripped thread made of, aluminum? You may get lucky at a local welding or machine shop. Adding metal to a hole, then re-threading is a possible option, if you've access to the equipment. The piece itself looks custom as all get out, which translates to $$$.

Comment: It is a specialty item, but it's probably still just referred as a hinge (for a top-hinge cabinet, I assume). Are these custom cabinets? Since at least the early 1990's, most cabinet companies have a lifetime warranty on the hardware. Can you find a brand name? It's usually on a tag inside the sink base cabinet.

Comment: We will at least need a picture of a complete device. Usually the name of the maker is on the main body of the device somewhere.

Comment: Agreed: what was it being used in? It may not have a name or be available outside that manufacture's parts lists.